# How can I get all relationships on a table?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following:
DB Models

```
class Book(Base):
  __table_name__ = 'books'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  chapters = relationship("Chapter", backref="book")

class Chapter(Base):
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String)
```

The `Book` model has a relationship to `Chapter`, to try and get the relationships belonging to the BOOK or any table for that matter I have the following incomplete function:

```
   def get_related_tables(self, table_name)
       
        model = self.get_class_by_table_name(table_name)
        print(f"The model {model}")
        query = session.query(model) # I can query the Model, but I want to get a list of all tables that are related to it
```

If I call the function with "books" `get_related_tables("books")`, I expect the output to be `[<Chapter>]`

How can I get a list of relationships belonging to a Model?

Answer (score 2):

You can call [inspect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/inspection.html?highlight=inspect#module-sqlalchemy.inspection) on the model class to get its related `mapper`.  The `mapper` has a relationships property which returns a mapping of relationship details:

```
>>> import sqlalchemy as sa
>>> insp = sa.inspect(Book)
>>> insp.relationships.items()
[('chapters', <RelationshipProperty at 0x7f71315ffec0; chapters>)]
```

A [RelationshipProperty](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.RelationshipProperty)'s attributes are not individually documented, but you can learn about them by reading the general [relationship documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationships.html#relationship-configuration).